# PHP preg_match with optional math rules

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, optional-parameters, option-type

I want to parse this string and get special values
string to parse have one of these patterns

```
app/(integer)/(integer)/(text or null)
app/(integer)/(text or null)
app/(text or null)
```

I can use `preg_match` for simple use but I can't write optional params

```
preg_match('%app/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\.*)$%', $text, $matches)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
$urls = array(
    'app/12/34/text',
    'app/12/34/',
    'app/56/text',
    'app/56/',
    'app/text',
    'app/',
);
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    preg_match( "#app/(?:(\d+)/)?(?:(\d+)/)?(.*)#", $url, $m);
    print_r($m);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => app/12/34/text
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 34
    [3] => text
)
Array
(
    [0] => app/12/34/
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 34
    [3] =>
)
Array
(
    [0] => app/56/text
    [1] => 56
    [2] =>
    [3] => text
)
Array
(
    [0] => app/56/
    [1] => 56
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
)
Array
(
    [0] => app/text
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] => text
)
Array
(
    [0] => app/
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your given patterns result in the following cases u want to match:

```
app/1/2/foo
app/1/2/
app/1/bar
app/1/
app/bar
app/
```

This can be achieved using a regex with the OR operator ( | ).
Syntax would be as follows:

```
~app/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\w+)|app/(\d+)/(\d+)/|app/(\d+)/(\w+)|app/(\d+)/|app/(\w+)|app/$~
```

I built a regex101 "fiddle" for exactly your case:
http://regex101.com/r/zT9jT6/1

Note that "app/" will match match with 0 entries in your $matches array.

et voilà.